# Use postman to get a token from a request and send it to another

Tags: api, rest, postman

I am using postman to do some testing on a REST API.

To login I use a post request who respond with a token I need to keep to use it with another request.

I did it that way :
[image]

and then I want to use it in another request who need that token in the header :

[image]

I seems that it's not sending the token. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I see the example you have posted in question actually worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `postman.setEnvironmentVariable()` instead of `postman.setGlobalVariable()`.

I found the answer [here](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/)

Answer (score 7):

Let's say the login response is:

```
{
   "message": {
        "token":"Some token value here"
    }
}
```

There is a slight change in the latest postman and here is the syntax to set variable:

```
var data = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("token", data.message.token);
```

Read here more information:
https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/variables/

Answer (score 3):

I have used the below script in the Tests tab of the postman and it worked for me.

```
pm.environment.set("access_token", JSON.parse(responseBody).access_token);
```

After setting the access token in my first API, I am passing that access token in my second API.

Answer (score 0):

You can save token to an environment variable and access in any requests under that collection. May be this link will be helpful:

[Extracting data from responses and chaining requests](https://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Login API
2. Go to "Tests" tab.
3. Add folowing script. This script will set variable "AuthToken" with response token.

   var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
   postman.setEnvironmentVariable("AuthToken", jsonData.data.accessToken);

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Gaurav's answer above, probably checking the status of the response first would be more nicer:

```
if(pm.response.code === 200) {
    pm.environment.set('authToken', pm.response.json().token)
}
```